# App update is not showing on google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, google-play, updates

I have updated my app on google play store, [previous : 1(1.0)  new : 2(1.1)] Its showing as updated on console, and on play store, version is showing as 1.1 but update button is not showing up, I have checked on multiple devices. and if we install, it will install update app. Please help with this issue. Screenshots attached.

Edit : I have re-updated app with few minor changes. (version 1.1.1 and version code 3), but still can't see the update on play store.

Version uploaded on play store (version code : 3)
[image: On Play store]

Version Installed in my device(version code : 1)
[image: In my device]

Comment: Did you perhaps already have the 1.1 version installed on your device(s) from development and testing?

Comment: 1.0 version is installed on my device. with version code as 1

Comment: Did you wait long enough for the device / Google Play caching to expire? Maybe show some screenshots that show the current version on your device, the version on the app store, and the lack of the update button.

Comment: @dominicoder have uploaded ss, please check...

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably your new version have the version code `2` but the version name `1.0` same as the previous build.
You can check this from Google Play Console.

**UPDATE:** I can see the new version

[image: screenshot]

Comment: nope, that's not the case, have named all versions differently, at present 3(1.1.1) is on play store and 1(1.0) is on my device.

Comment: could you share the link to the app on Play store?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.affixchat.chatappv0

Comment: @OJ2002 I can see the new version (I've updated my answer with screenshot)